# Chrome multiple tabs per page

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

Is there a way to essentially "combine" two or more chrome tabs into one view. So instead of having to flip between tabs to compare things I can see them both on the screen at the same time. Obviously I can run two apps but I would like to avoid doing that.

Comment: did you get your query solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Split Screen](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eachfleknamlcepmplpdghagngjfjkin) extension works fine. Please find the Screenshot

[image: below]

Hope this proves the point

Comment: This is the closest one that does what I want. It would be nice to easily be able to combine, close, or split tabs with just a click or two(e.g., open link in split tab).

Answer (score 2):

Two extensions from the Chrome Web Store seem suitable in your case:

[*Split Screen*](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eachfleknamlcepmplpdghagngjfjkin)
opens a new tab and prompts the user for two URL's, then displays both sites on one page (from extension's description).

[Frame two pages](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eldgpcphflnopbjadiaonofideekgdgm) merges the active tab and the previous one into a frameset. In other words, your physical screen will be split into two areas.

The second one is more flexible (in the sense that you have more options for the splitting, and that you can have more than one split in the same tab), but maybe less simple to use.

Comment: I tried the first option (split screen), but it didnt work all that well.

Comment: Link-only answers are a no-no on SU due to possible future link-rot.  Please edit your answer and elaborate on what these plug-ins are and how they could be useful in this situation.